# Align header elements with left middle right order

Tags: html, css

I want to align my elements in my header so they are positioned, like this:

`LOGO       SEARCH       LINK|LINK`

The logo begins on far left, while the search is in middle, and the links on the right, while that I want the search to be max width of the space between the div's of logo and siteMeta and I don't want to break responsiveness.

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}
#logo {
  float: left;
  max-width: 220px;
}
#search {
  float: left;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-top: 75px;
}
#siteMeta {
  float: left;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 220px;
  line-height: 220px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div id="search">
      <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group add-on">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" type="text">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="siteMeta">
      <a href="#">Link</a>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with the `calc` value for the `width` property.

I've had to add the following things to your css. I've replaced your `max-width` properties with `width` and added some backgrounds to better observe the result.

```
#search{
    width: calc(100% - 220px - 300px);
}

#search input {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#siteMeta{
    width: 300px;
}

#logo{
    width: 220px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9h3zm2sc/

If you want a wider range of support you can also solve it with the following:

```
* {
     box-sizing: border-box;
}

#search{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-left: 220px; /* width of the logo */
    padding-right: 300px; /* width of the siteMeta */
}

#siteMeta{
    float: right;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mehabrzz/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can make `#header` a table, and its children elements `table-cells` having `width: 33%;`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}
#header {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  }
#header > * {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33%;
  }
#logo {
}
#search {
  margin-top: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}
#siteMeta {
  text-align: right;
  height: 220px;
  line-height: 220px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div id="search">
        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
          <div class="input-group add-on">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" type="text">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="siteMeta">
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS Tables can do this.

A simplified layout

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
#header,
#logo,
#search,
#siteMeta {
  display: table-cell;
}
#siteMeta a {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
#search {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
      LOGO
    </div>

    <div id="search">
      <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group add-on">
          SEARCH
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="siteMeta">
      <a href="#">Link</a>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply without table and flex:

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:center;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
}
#logo {
 float:left;
 width:33%;
}
#search {
  float: left;
  width:33%;
}
#siteMeta {
  float: left;
  width:33%;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div id="search">
        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
          <div class="input-group add-on">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" type="text">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="siteMeta">
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
      </div>

    </div>
```